# Create a list of objects before adding it to an object in an object array?

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

I'm trying my best to create a very simple GUI application which "kind-of" acts the same as a Micros System which would be used in places like restaurants. I advise to read the code, which is commented, before reading the question, it will be easier to understand :)

So my question is. I firstly created a GUI with buttons which when clicked added Meal objects to a single Bill. No table choosing was required as only one Bill existed, and I was able to display the items on that Bill and view the price without any issues. My extra weak point in Java is Arrays, which is sort of why I wanted to try to create something like this, but I am really stuck on this one.

I want to have a way to have a Bill for each of 10 Tables. I have added an ActionListener to the JComboBox and using it to asign a table number using the selected number in the JComboBox. At the same time, it creates a Bill object and assigns it a Table Number. Simple right?

Where I am having trouble is how I can add Meals to a Bill in relation to the selected table number? I am sure I cannot be far off it. Like I want to be able to View the bill in relation to the JComboBox selected number and be able to create other Bills for Tables, add items, come back later and view the relavent table number Bill again.

I hope I explained as much as possible. Anybody who lends their time to help, I sincerely thank. All code below.

Main Class:

```
/** Created by Alan on 19/11/2016 */

public class MicrosMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micros micros = new Micros();
        micros.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Micros Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/** Created by Alan on 19/11/2016 */

public class Micros extends JFrame {
    // Create Local Variables

    private String[] tableNumbers;

    private Bill userBill = new Bill();
    private ArrayList<Bill> allBills = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Meal> allMeals = new ArrayList<>();

    // Create Global JItem Variables
    private JComboBox comboBox;
    private JComboBox<String> tableList;

    // Micros Menu
    private Meal curry = new Meal("Chicken Curry", 10.00);
    private Meal spaghetti = new Meal("Spaghetti Bolognese", 15.00);
    private Meal steak = new Meal("Steak Sandwich", 20.00);
    private Meal tea = new Meal("Lyons Tea", 2.00);
    private Meal coffee = new Meal("Bewleys Coffee", 3.00);
    private Meal hotChocolate = new Meal("Hot Chocolate", 4.00);

    // Constructor Method

    Micros()
    {
        // Set The JFrame Properties ------------------------------------------------------------------
        super("MicrosSys");
        setSize(230, 515);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(800, 250);

        // ---------------------------------- Create The Container ----------------------------------
        Container cPane = getContentPane();
        cPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        cPane.setLayout(null);

        // ---------------------------------- Create The Welcome/Instruction Label ----------------------------------
        Color red = Color.decode("#ff0000");

        JLabel areaLabel = new JLabel("Welcome");
        areaLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        areaLabel.setForeground(red);
        areaLabel.setLocation(65, 5);
        areaLabel.setSize(200, 30);
        cPane.add(areaLabel);
        areaLabel = new JLabel("Choose A Table Number Then");
        areaLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        areaLabel.setLocation(30, 30);
        areaLabel.setSize(200, 30);
        cPane.add(areaLabel);
        areaLabel = new JLabel("Choose What You Want");
        areaLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        areaLabel.setLocation(45, 50);
        areaLabel.setSize(200, 30);
        cPane.add(areaLabel);
        areaLabel = new JLabel("- Choose A Table Number -");
        areaLabel.setForeground(red);
        areaLabel.setLocation(35, 80);
        areaLabel.setSize(200, 30);
        cPane.add(areaLabel);

        // --------------------------------- Create ComboBox for Choosing the Table Number --------------------
        tableList = new JComboBox<String>();
        tableList.addActionListener(new actionListener());
        String[] initialValue = {"- Choose A Table -"};
        tableList.addItem(initialValue[0]);
        for(int x = 1; x <= userBill.getNumOfTables(); x++)
        {
            tableList.addItem(String.valueOf(x));
        }

        DefaultListCellRenderer centerText = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
        centerText.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultListCellRenderer.CENTER);
        tableList.setRenderer(centerText);
        tableList.setLocation(10,105);
        tableList.setSize(200,20);
        cPane.add(tableList);

        // ---------------------------------- Create The Food Label ----------------------------------
        areaLabel = new JLabel("Food Items");
        areaLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        areaLabel.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        areaLabel.setLocation(10, 130);
        areaLabel.setSize(200, 30);
        cPane.add(areaLabel);

        // ---------------------------------- Create The Food Buttons ----------------------------------
        JButton menuButton = new JButton(curry.toString());
        menuButton.setLocation(10, 170);
        menuButton.setSize(200, 30);
        menuButton.addActionListener(new actionListener());
        cPane.add(menuButton);
        menuButton = new JButton(spaghetti.toString());
        menuButton.setLocation(10, 210);
        menuButton.setSize(200, 30);
        menuButton.addActionListener(new actionListener());
        cPane.add(menuButton);
        menuButton = new JButton(steak.toString());
        menuButton.setLocation(10, 250);
        menuButton.setSize(200, 30);
        menuButton.addActionListener(new actionListener());
        cPane.add(menuButton);

        // ---------------------------------- Create The Drinks Label ----------------------------------
        areaLabel = new JLabel("Drink Items");
        areaLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        areaLabel.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        areaLabel.setLocation(10, 300);
        areaLabel.setSize(200, 30);
        cPane.add(areaLabel);

        // ---------------------------------- Create The Drink Buttons ----------------------------------
        menuButton = new JButton(tea.toString());
        menuButton.setLocation(10, 340);
        menuButton.setSize(200, 30);
        menuButton.addActionListener(new actionListener());
        cPane.add(menuButton);
        menuButton = new JButton(coffee.toString());
        menuButton.setLocation(10, 380);
        menuButton.setSize(200, 30);
        menuButton.addActionListener(new actionListener());
        cPane.add(menuButton);
        menuButton = new JButton(hotChocolate.toString());
        menuButton.setLocation(10, 420);
        menuButton.setSize(200, 30);
        menuButton.addActionListener(new actionListener());
        cPane.add(menuButton);
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Create The 'View' Menu To Hold Items
        JMenu billMenu = new JMenu("Bill");

        // Create Items To Add To 'View' Menu
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("View Bill");
        menuItem.addActionListener(new actionListener()); // Action Listener For When 'View Bill' Is Clicked
        billMenu.add(menuItem); // Add 'View Bill' To The Bill Menu

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Pay Bill");
        menuItem.addActionListener(new actionListener());
        billMenu.add(menuItem);

        // Create The 'File' Menu To Hold Items
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

        //Create Items To Add To 'File' Menu
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit"); // New Menu Item Called Exit
        menuItem.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0)); // Action Listener For When 'Exit' Is Clicked
        fileMenu.add(menuItem); // Add 'Exit' To The File Menu

        // Create Menu Bar To Add Menus
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        menuBar.add(billMenu);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        // Add The Menu Bar To The Frame
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    public class actionListener extends Bill implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
        {
            // Action Listener for the JComboBox which will create a new userBill in relation to the chosen table
            if(a.getSource() == tableList)
            {
                String tableChosen = tableList.getSelectedItem().toString();
                int tableNumber;

                if (!tableChosen.equals("- Choose A Table -"))
                {
                    tableNumber = Integer.parseInt(tableChosen);
                    userBill = new Bill();
                    userBill.setTableNum(tableNumber);
                    System.out.println("Table Number Set and Bill Created");
                }
            }

            // --------------------------- View Bill Option ---------------------------
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals("View Bill")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userBill.getBillList());
            }

            // --------------------------- Pay Bill Option ---------------------------
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals("Pay Bill")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Bill Total Is: €" + userBill.getBillTotal());
            }

            /* ************************************************************************************************************************************************ */
            /* ************************************************************************************************************************************************ */

            // --------------------------- Food Item Number One ---------------------------
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals(curry.toString())) {
                userBill.setBill(curry);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, curry.getName() + " Added To Bill");
            }

            // --------------------------- Food Item Number Two ---------------------------
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals(spaghetti.toString())) {
                userBill.setBill(spaghetti);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spaghetti.getName() + " Added To Bill");
            }

            // --------------------------- Food Item Number Three ---------------------------
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals(steak.toString())) {
                userBill.setBill(steak);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, steak.getName() + " Added To Bill");
            }

            // --------------------------- Drink Item Number One ---------------------------
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals(tea.toString())) {
                userBill.setBill(tea);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tea.getName() + " Added To Bill");
            }

            // --------------------------- Drink Item Number Two ---------------------------
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals(coffee.toString())) {
                userBill.setBill(coffee);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, coffee.getName() + " Added To Bill");
            }

            // --------------------------- Drink Item Number Three ---------------------------
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals(hotChocolate.toString())) {
                userBill.setBill(hotChocolate);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, hotChocolate.getName() + " Added To Bill");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bill Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/** Created by Alan on 19/11/2016 */

public class Bill {

    private int tableNum;
    private static int billNum;
    private double billTotal;
    private ArrayList<Meal> mealList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Bill ()
    {
        billNum++;
        tableNum = 0;
        mealList = null;
    }

    public void setTableNum (int tableNum)
    {
        this.tableNum = tableNum;
    }


    public void setBill (Meal meal)
    {
        mealList.add(meal);
        billTotal += meal.getPrice();
    }

    public int getNumOfTables ()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public double getBillTotal ()
    {
        return this.billTotal;
    }

    public JTextArea getBillList ()
    {
        String billFormat = "";
        JTextArea billArea = new JTextArea();
        billArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        billArea.append(String.format("%-20s %-10s\n\n","Name","Price"));

        for(Meal i : mealList)
        {
            billFormat += String.format("%-20s €%-10s\n",i.getName(), i.getPrice());
            billArea.append(billFormat);
            billFormat = "";
        }

        billArea.append("\nTotal Price: €" + billTotal);
        billArea.setEditable(false);
        return billArea;
    }
}
```

Meal Class:

```
/** Created by Alan on 19/11/2016 */

public class Meal {

    private String name;
    private double price;

    public Meal () {}

    public Meal (String name, double price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public double getPrice ()
    {
        return this.price;
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
        return String.format("%s - €%.2f", this.getName(),this.getPrice());
    }
}
```

Food Class:

```
/** Created by Alan on 19/11/2016 */

public class Food {

    private String name;
    private double price;

    public Food () {}

    public Food (String name, double price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public double getPrice ()
    {
        return this.price;
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
        return String.format("%s - €%.2f", this.getName(),this.getPrice());
    }
}
```

Drink Class:

```
/** Created by Alan on 19/11/2016 */

public class Drink {

    private String name;
    private double price;

    public Drink () {}

    public Drink (String name, double price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public double getPrice ()
    {
        return this.price;
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
        return String.format("%s - €%.2f", this.getName(),this.getPrice());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your problem. What you need to do is use a data structure that maintains the relationships that you are exploiting in the model.

Tables own Bills, Bills own Meals. Assuming a Table owns many Bills and a Bill might own multiple Meals, simply use a `Map<Table, Collection<Bill>>` and a `Map<Bills, Collection<Meal>>`. The first Map will allow you to get all the Bills owned by a given Table and the second Map will allow you to keep the Meals owned by any given Bill. You can modify the Maps to allow for the use of the Table index by using a `Map<Integer, Collection<Bill>>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by using Map> I never heard of it before. Any link where you know there would be a good example? Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. Maps are associative data structures. You can find more information about them here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/90/collections/12413/usage-of-hashmap#t=201611292043494826684.